# DevTools Lighthouse: Best Practices displays "..." as a Deprecation/Warning

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm testing the performance of my website with Lighthouse DevTool but I can't score 100% in Best Practices because keeps showing this as a problem:
[image: Lighthouse Deprecation/Warning]

Does anybody know what this means? How could I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the specific errors in the "Issues" tab where the "Console" output is.

[image: Issues tab]

Answer (score 1):

Also getting this, so you're not alone. Wondering if it was a recent Chrome bug I tried here - https://www.webpagetest.org/ and got the same useless error.

After a bit more digging, I found this closed issue on the lighthouse github repo.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/14233

So, it's been fixed, but only in version 10. Chrome 105 seems to be using lighthouse `9.6.2` and npm at the present time seems to install `9.6.7` (which has the same bug).

You can run the latest version by pulling the repo from github, building and running on the command line. See instructions here

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse#develop

Note, the build doesn't work on an M1 mac, due to i386 specific build tools. I had to dig out my old macbook to get this working.