# Null deprecated API

Tags: lighthouse

When I run lighthouse, Google indicates that I have a deprecated API. It doesn't provide any details on what it is though.

[image]

Any thoughts on how to track this down? The site is cleanwithpristine.net.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73666680/devtools-lighthouse-best-practices-displays-as-a-deprecation-warning/74674899#74674899?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DevTools Lighthouse: Best Practices displays "..." as a Deprecation/Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73666680/devtools-lighthouse-best-practices-displays-as-a-deprecation-warning)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved per github

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/14233